# find if record exist by given values compration

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like this:
roleID | permissionID

now both columns are int types.
I need to find by given permissionID's to check if there exist
a roleID that is within that permissionID.

I have tried to search for some solution online but couldn't find one. I pretty sure I'm not finding the right word to read more about it

for example the tables looks like this:

```
roleID          permissionID
1                   1
1                   2
1                   4
2                   4
2                   1
3                   4
```

for example I receive ids 1,2,4 that they are the permissionID and I see that roleID 1 has all that relation to him.
edit: the given roleID needs to match exactly to the permissionID count, if it has more than in given values then don't count as found.
thanks for the effort all who willing to help!

Comment: you're right im sorry I got messed with the editor here, fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by roleid and put the condition in HAVING clause:

```
select
  roleid
from tablename
where permissionid in (1, 2, 4)
group by roleid
having count(distinct permissionid) = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dTCGuTz3JXCPpe9nFwP1ga/0).
Results:

```
| roleid |
| ------ |
| 1      |
```

Edit, to get the roleids that have only the permissions in the list:

```
select
  roleid
from tablename
group by roleid
having 
  count(distinct permissionid) = 3
  and
  sum(permissionid not in (1, 2, 4)) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dTCGuTz3JXCPpe9nFwP1ga/1).

Comment: I forgot to mention something but I need a query that will find like only the exact match by given values. for  example if I have a roleID that has all those permission but has 1 more so don't count it as found. this query working fine except it return multi

Comment: I tried out but it still gives me multi results when only one roleID is matched, this roleID 3. ```select roleid
      from `project_role_permissions`
      where permissionid in (11,12,10,13,14)
      group by roleid
      having count(distinct permissionid) = '5'
         and
         sum(permissionid not in (11,12,10,13,14)) = 0
      ``` return me result of roleID 1 and roleID 3, when roleID 1 has all permission that roleID 3 and more

Comment: For your sample data as you can see in the demo the result is roleid = 1.

Comment: Remove `where permissionid in (11,12,10,13,14)`

Comment: thanks!! It's working exactly as I wanted for too many hours.. you're a life saver!